# Linq - Many to Many. select with dropdown

Tags: c#, linq

I got these 3 tables

```
tblDocument(DocId, DocName)
tblSubPerson(DocId, PersonId)
tblPerson(PersonId, PersonName)
```

ddlPerson has all my persons relatet to it.

i'm trying to write a linq query where i want to return all the documents ind tblDocument where the selected person has a relation to and display it in a repeter

got this far.... don't know if i'm doing it wrong

```
public void testing()
{
    string se = ddlPerson.SelectedValue;
    var data = new MyModelContext();
    rptResult.DataSource = from y in data.tblDocuments
                           join p in data.tblSubPersons on y.DocId equals p.DocId
                           select p.PersonId.Equals(se);
    rptResult.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query returns collection of `bool` values, because that's what `Equals()` method returns. You should use `where` clause to get only documents for given person:

```
var personId = int.Parse(ddlPerson.SelectedValue);

var data = new MyModelContext();

var documents = from d in data.tblDocumenta
                join sp in data.tblSubPerson on d.DocId equals sp.DocId
                where sp.PersonId == personId 
                select d;

rptResult.DataSource = documents.ToList();
rptResult.DataBind();
```

Comment: the "==" operator cannot be used when the personId is a int and the dropdown is a string. tried to convert the dropdown to a int32. but dosent work.. :/ any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using `int.Parse`? I've updated my answer.

Comment: getting a "Input string was not in a correct format." error.

i'v added "var data = new MyModelContext();" to your answer.

Comment: ok, then you should try and check what value you actually get in `ddlPerson.SelectedValue`.

Comment: thank you very much for you help. I've found the solution. My datavaluefield for my dropdown was at fault :)